# In Clojurescript, how do I change a web page's title?

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure

I'd like to change the title of the page in the browser using Clojurescript. I'm using Google Closure for dom manipulation, I'm open to functions inside Closure to do this.

In pure javascript, you can just do this:

```
window.document.title = "pants";
```

But I can't figure out how that translates into Clojurescript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`(set! (. js/document -title) "new title")`

Answer (score 2):

another way

```
(aset js/document "title" "new title")
```